# Remove () and - and white spaces from phone number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a phone number like (123) 456-7891. I need number like 1234567891.

How can I do that in Javascript ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [String.replace()](http://www.javascripture.com/String#replace) to do this.  Pass it a [RegExp](http://www.javascripture.com/RegExp) that matches everything but digits and replace them with `''`.

```
var number = '(123) 456-7891';
number = number.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 22):

To be on the safe side, I would recommend removing everything except `+` (for country codes) and digits:

```
result = subject.replace(/[^+\d]+/g, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

`alert("(123) 456-7891".replace(/[\(\)\-\s]+/g, ''));`

Comment: alert? why is there an alert

Comment: Alert is used here to just print out the result of the expression. It could have been console.log as well. However a bit more context information (even if the answer is trivial) might help less experienced users to better understand it.

Answer (score 0):

please check this link.it might help you

http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php

there are many examples here.it might be useful for you.